# Can a workflow badge be retrieved with the GitHub API?

Tags: github, github-actions, github-api-v3

The GitHub API documentation shows an [example](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/actions/workflows) for retrieving repository workflows.

The response includes a `badge_url` field for each workflow. For example:

```
"badge_url": "https://github.com/octo-org/octo-repo/workflows/CI/badge.svg"
```

Is it possible to retrieve the badge using the GitHub API? My question arises for a scenario where I'm trying to retrieve the badge for a private repository, and it would be more convenient to use the GitHub API versus alternative approaches.

Comment: Can you please show what you have tried and how that does not solve your use-case? What do you mean with "more convenient"? In any case, if you're looking for something like `api.github.com....` I doubt that exists.

Comment: The request is made from a web page. I've tried accessing the URL directly, using an `<img>` element with `crossorigin="use-credentials"`, but this doesn't work since GitHub doesn't provide an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header. By "more convenient", I was thinking there could be alternative approaches like a server-side request, but this webapp runs fully in the browser (no server calls). I was looking for something that uses `api.github.com`. I know the API can be used to request files (e.g., repository files, workflow artifacts), so I thought badges may be available some way too.